# center of gravity given four weights

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I have this problem. I have four points that corresponds to four vertices of rectangle. 
Every vertex has a load cell that return a weight. How can I calculate the center of gravity, in a range of 0-100?

Any idea?
Thanks

--- EDIT ----

Look the image:
[image: Lorem Ipsum.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the origin be one corner of the rectangle and the $x$ axis along the length $L$.  If the width is $W$ you have measurements at $(0,0),(L,0),(0,W),(L,W)$.  If $w(x,y)$ is the weight measured at $x,y$ you have the $x$ position of the CG is 
$$x_{CG}=\frac {w(L,0)+w(L,W)}{w(L,0)+w(L,W)+w(0,W+w(0,0)}L$$
If you want a value in $[0,100]$ you probably mean the percentage of the length, so divide this by the length and express it in percent.  Do the same in the other axis.

Comment: I edited the question. With your formula I find x position. With the y I have to use (0,0) and (0,W)? And I do not understand the 0-100 calculation...

Comment: No, with $y$ you use $(0,W)$ and $(L,W)$ in the numerator and multiply by $W$.  I forgot a factor $L$ in the numerator.  Am I correct that your $0$ to $100$ is supposed to be percent of the size of the object?  More usually you would just report the $x,y$ coordinates of the CG.

Comment: x,y of CG is correct. But, there is a smart way to represent this with one number, instead of two?

Comment: Maybe the shift of the CG compared to the last value...

Comment: The CG is a point in two dimensions for a flat object, so you are asking to represent a point with one number.  Of course you can do $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and report the distance.  If you have a prior value you can report the distance between them.  Basically, you have two coordinates and reporting one value is throwing away information.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your centre of gravity is at point $P(x,y)$

Let's calculate the $x$ coordinate of the gravity centre.

$$x=\frac{10*0+20*0+0*0+5*L}{10+20+0+5}=\frac{5L}{35}=\frac{L}{7}$$
$$y=\frac{10*0+20*L+0*W+5*W}{35}=\frac{4L+W}{7}$$

Comment: Thanks, but, there is a smart way to represent this with one number, instead of two?

Comment: $$P(L/7,(4L+W)/7)$$